# Как получить -NaN в C++ 14

Tags: c++, c++14

Как в C++ 14 с компилятором g++ (GNU C++) 4.7.2 получить значение переменной типа `double = -NaN`, используя только арифметические действия?

Comment: а просто `-nan("");` нельзя?

Comment: @pavel Вся суть заключается в получение -nan с помощью арифметических действий, так что ответ (INFINITY_NUMBER / INFINITY_NUMBER) = -NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Самый простой способ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sT5L9kkgp1yp1hOs) - поделить ноль на ноль (вещественный).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double zero = 0;
    std::cout << 0/zero << "\n";
}
```

Вывод:

> ```
> -nan
> ```

Comment: Хм, а чем отличается от +nan?

Comment: @VladD на этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45447125/3240681) ответа пока нет. Наверное надо его выделить отдельно.

Comment: @VladD [выделил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700900/176217)

Answer (score 1):

Я решил:
INFINITY_NUMBER / INFINITY_NUMBER = -NaN