# Смысловая нагрузка значения "минус NaN"

Tags: c++, nan

В другом вопросе [обнаружилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/700757/176217), что деление нуля на переменную, содержащую вещественный ноль, в результате даёт значение `-nan`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double zero = 0;
    std::cout << 0/zero << "\n";
}
```

Результат получается одинаковым для основных наиболее популярных компиляторов:

- [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HKXLpYEMLoeBmZkb)
- [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jf9wL5M6RtJM4abS)
- [MSVC](http://rextester.com/JEYA84440)

Есть ли какой-то практический смысл в этом минусе, почему не просто `nan`?

Comment: А зачем `+0/-0` в JS?

Comment: @Aid с нулём это можно объяснить стремлением с той или иной стороны. Тут же исходные аргументы не отрицательные.

Comment: я бы поставил на оптимизацию. http://ideone.com/U1QxkB вот тут чуть понятнее (или нет...)

Comment: @pavel хотите сказать, что просто вычисления приводят к установке знакового бита, а снимать его - лишнее действие, поэтому остаётся минус?

Comment: @alexolut как гипотеза - да.

Comment: @alexolut деления то нету на самом деле. `a/b == a * (1/b)` теперь смотрим. http://ideone.com/BkwywT но странно, что если 1 заменить на -1, то конечный ответ не меняется. В общем ждём более опытного кого-то.

Comment: @pavel бесконечность, умноженная на ноль - это явная неопределённость. Тот же `nan`, и снова с минусом.

Comment: [Тут](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130221-00/?p=5183) есть ответ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Получается это из-за того, что все вышеозначенные примеры были запущены на x86 архитектуре, а для FPU оной есть такое правило:

> When neither of the source operands is a NaN, but the operation
>   generates a floating-point invalid-operation exception (see Tables
>   8-10 and 11-1), the result is commonly a QNaN FP Indefinite (Section
>   4.8.3.7).

Взятое из [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 1: Basic Architecture](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf) параграфа 4.8.3.5.

Заглянув в таблицу, указанную в цитате выше, мы обнаружим там следующую операцию, которая даёт на выходе QNaN:

> Division: ∞ by ∞ ; 0 by 0.

Т.е. как раз то, что у нас и есть в вопросе (там есть и другие операции). А если мы посмотрим на таблицу 4-3, из секции 4.2.2, то увидим, что у QNaN знаковый бит выставлен в 1, что объясняет появление отрицательного NaN в выводе.

---

А если посмотреть на это всё с точки зрения языка, то получается неопределённое поведение, поэтому видеть мы можем всё, что угодно.

**C++14, [expr]p4:**

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is undefined.

---

Ответ навеян замечательный [постом](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130221-00/?p=5183) от Реймонда Чена.

Comment: Надо проверить на ARM что ли. Найти бы только где. И что-то не очень понятно, в чём отличия `QNaN Floating-Point Indefinite` от просто `QNaN`.

Comment: @alexolut, отличия в том, что эти два NaN получаются по разному, посмотрите таблицу 8-10 (поиском по pdf Table 8-10), там указано при каких обстоятельствах получается просто QNaN, а при каких QNaN Ind

Comment: Да, только это определение из стандарта - нечеткое. Деление 0 на 0 mathematically defined в IEEE 756 - это NaN. В данном случае Стандарт намеренно расплывчат.

Comment: @SergeyA, ну да, стандарт не определяет, что «mathematically defined» вообще означает, поэтому тут можно фантазировать всё, что угодно.